# IF condition in DAX is creating Cartesian Join on rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

Dax formula without If condition works fine, but as soon as I add an IF condition rows start multiplying. I believe it's doing Cartesian Product.

My requirement is simple. I need to show only those rows in which `Sickness[Start_Date]>LASTDATE(Test[Date])`

The complete formula is -

```
Measure = 
var val = CALCULATE(MAX(Sickness[Start_Date]),FILTER(Sickness,Sickness[Start_Date]>LASTDATE(Test[Date])),ALL())
return
IF(val = BLANK(),0,1)
```

I have 3 separate tables **Emp_data**, **Test** and **Sickness**.

To replicate this scenario, Please follow the below steps:

1st Step : Create table **Emp_data**

```
Emp_data = DATATABLE("Emp_no",INTEGER,"Name",STRING,{{101,"A"},
{102,"B"},
{103,"C"},
{104,"D"},
{105,"E"},
{106,"F"},
{107,"G"},
{108,"I"},
{109,"J"},
{110,"K"},
{111,"L"},
{112,"N"},
{113,"M"},
{114,"O"},
{115,"P"},
{116,"Q"},
{117,"R"},
{118,"S"},
{119,"T"},
{120,"U"}
})
```

create table : **Test**

```
Test = DATATABLE("Emp_No",INTEGER,"Date",DATETIME,"Result",INTEGER,{{101,"3/10/2020",1},
{101,"3/13/2020",2},
{102,"3/11/2020",1},
{103,"3/12/2020",2},
{104,"3/13/2020",1},
{105,"3/14/2020",1},
{106,"3/15/2020",2},
{107,"3/16/2020",1},
{108,"4/20/2020",1},
{109,"4/21/2020",2},
{110,"4/22/2020",2},
{111,"4/23/2020",1},
{112,"4/24/2020",1},
{113,"4/25/2020",2},
{114,"4/26/2020",1},
{115,"4/27/2020",2},
{116,"5/5/2020",1},
{117,"5/5/2020",1},
{118,"5/5/2020",1},
{119,"5/5/2020",1},
{120,"5/5/2020",2}
})
```

Create table **Sickness**

```
Sickness = DATATABLE("Emp_no",INTEGER,"Start_Date",DATETIME,"End_Date",DATETIME,"Sickness_Code",INTEGER,{{101,"2/12/2020","2/12/2020",30},
{101,"3/10/2020","3/15/2020",50},
{101,"3/20/2020","3/30/2020",50},
{101,"4/5/2020","4/10/2020",40},
{102,"3/11/2020","3/11/2020",50},
{107,"3/1/2020","3/2/2020",30},
{107,"3/15/2020","3/20/2020",50},
{107,"3/21/2020","3/31/2020",40},
{112,"4/20/2020","4/30/2020",50},
{112,"5/1/2020","5/15/2020",50},
{116,"4/1/2020","4/15/2020",30},
{116,"5/3/2020","5/15/2020",50},
{116,"5/16/2020","5/26/2020",50},
{116,"5/27/2020","5/29/2020",40}}
)
```

Second Step is to create relationship between these 3 tables. **Emp_Data** and **Test** table have one to many relationship. I changed the filter direction to **BOTH**. Thinking may be this will resolve the issue. Create relation many to many between the tables **Test** and **Sickness**. The image is attached
[image]

The output  is as follows :

[image]

If I remove the IF condition my out is what I need :

[image]

Can someone help me in understanding this behavior of Power BI. This looks very strange. Why row count is increasing after applying IF condition. Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you assigned a 0 value to all blank values in your Sickness data table. Once your remove the if statement, Power BI only shows data rows that do not return a blank value.

To fix your issue try this updated meassure:

```
Measure = 
VAR val = CALCULATE(MAX(Sickness[Start_Date]),FILTER(Sickness,Sickness[Start_Date]>LASTDATE(Test[Date])),ALL())
VAR OneZero = IF(ISBLANK(val),0,1)
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Sickness[Emp_no],OneZero)
```

Comment: @Pete : I need both the values 1 and 0. I will filter out in visual filters as per the requirement. I removed my IF condition and also enabled Show Item with no Data option. This gives me the correct row count which includes Blanks and Dates. Now I just need to replace them with 0 and 1. See the screenshot https://ibb.co/sqC1rQq

Comment: My expected output is in this image : https://ibb.co/QNjj1BC

Comment: Finally, I was able to get the output. I modified your formula to get 0 and 1 values. The formula that I used : Measure = 
var ot  = CALCULATE(MAX(Sickness[Start_Date]),FILTER(Sickness,Sickness[Start_Date]>LASTDATE(Test[Date])),ALL())
var ot1  = CALCULATE(MAX(Sickness[Start_Date]),FILTER(Sickness,Sickness[Start_Date]<=LASTDATE(Test[Date])),ALL())
Return
IF(NOT(ISBLANK(ot)),1,IF(NOT(ISBLANK(ot1)),0)
)

Comment: @sam while I am not sure based on which criteria employees end up on your final table, I gave it my best guess and updated the measure above.

Comment: @sam just saw your reply. Glad you were able to solve it :)